# ActivityNotFound exception

Tags: android, firebase

when i run this code, i faced activity not fund exception. it tells to mention TuserActivity in manifest, i did everything, application installed successfully, but when i want to go TuserActivity application was closed.

> --------- beginning of crash 02-21 09:50:37.256
>   7711-7711/com.example.krushi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.krushi, PID: 7711
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.krushi/com.example.krushi.TuserActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class
>   com.example.krushi.TuserActivity is not accessible from class
>   android.app.Instrumentation
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.example.krushi.TuserActivity is not accessible from class
>   android.app.Instrumentation
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1591)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

main:

```
     import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public EditText emailId, passwd;
        Button btnSignUp;
        TextView signIn,txuser;
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            emailId = findViewById(R.id.ETemail);
            passwd = findViewById(R.id.ETpassword);
            btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
            signIn = findViewById(R.id.TVSignIn);
            txuser = findViewById(R.id.tuser);
            btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String emailID = emailId.getText().toString();
                    String paswd = passwd.getText().toString();
                    if (emailID.isEmpty()) {
                        emailId.setError("Enter your E-mail");
                        emailId.requestFocus();
                    } else if (paswd.isEmpty()) {
                        passwd.setError("Enter your password");
                        passwd.requestFocus();
                    } else if (emailID.isEmpty() && paswd.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fields Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (!(emailID.isEmpty() && paswd.isEmpty())) {
                        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailID, paswd).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Task task) {

                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                            "SignUp unsuccessful: " + task.getException().getMessage(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserActivity.class));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent I = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_Login.class);
                    startActivity(I);
                }
            });
            txuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TuserActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activity_Login"></activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <activity android:name=".UserActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".VerifyPhoneActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".TuserActivity"/>
</application>
```

TuserActivity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

class TuserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText tphnumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tphnumber = findViewById(R.id.tphone);

        findViewById(R.id.btSend).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String mobile = tphnumber.getText().toString().trim();

                if(mobile.isEmpty() || mobile.length() < 10){
                    tphnumber.setError("Enter a valid mobile");
                    tphnumber.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(TuserActivity.this, VerifyPhoneActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("mobile", mobile);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you declared Activity_Login activity in your manifest?

Comment: please share error display in logcat when app stop

Comment: yeah, i updated

Comment: share the code of TuserActivity as well

Comment: `public class TuserActivity` add public

Comment: yeah, i shared.

Answer (score 1):

Make your class `TuserActivity` public like this:

```
public class TuserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `setContentView()` You add `activity_main.xml` layout in both file `MainActivity.class` and `TuserActivity.class`. You should add different `layout file` in TuserActivity instate of `activity_main.xml`

Answer (score -1):

You have not added `Activity_Login` class in manifest file check once

Change like this `public class TuserActivity add public`

Comment: its already added `<activity android:name=".Activity_Login"></activity>`

Comment: i already added to manifest

Comment: Can you paste the TuserActivity code @AbhijithPoojary ?

Comment: okay.. i added.

Comment: `public class TuserActivity` add public AbhijithPoojary